# Operating on vector of custom objects in C++

Tags: c++, function, loops, vector, cout

I have a function that uses my custom object called Card to fill a vector with 52 cards.

```
vector<Card> createDeck() {
    vector<Card> myDeck;
    Card card;
    for(int i=0; i < 52; i++){
        card.setRank(i);
        card.setSuit(i);
        myDeck.push_back(card);
    }
    return myDeck;
}
```

In my main i call this createDeck() function and use it to fill another vector:

```
int main() {
    vector<Card> theDeck;
    theDeck = createDeck();
    Card someCard;
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        cout << theDeck(i).toString();
    }
}
```

I want to iterate through the vector and call my toString function (defined in my Card class) on each object. However, this code gives me the following error "Type 'vector' does not provide a call operator".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want `theDeck[i].toString();`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the line:

```
cout << theDeck(i).toString();
```

`theDeck` is vector, and for accessing individual elements you either need to use subscript operator *i.e* `theDeck[i].toString()` or better to use `.at` function as it will check bounds also so you can use:

```
cout << theDeck.at(i).toString();
```

UPDATE:
Based on paddy comments it seems `.at` is not proper use case for this and reserve is definitely a good idea.So here is the updated code :

```
void createDeck(vector<Card>& myDeck){

Card card;
for(int i=0; i < 52; i++){
    card.setRank(i);
    card.setSuit(i);
    myDeck.push_back(card);
}

}
int main() {
vector<Card> theDeck;
theDeck.reserve(52);
createDeck(theDeck);
Card someCard;
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    cout << theDeck[i].toString();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would just like to raise a disagreement with "better to use .at".  In this case, the array size is bounded in the program, and so is the test.  We are dealing with a deck which is known to have 52 cards.  For brevity's sake, and since you are thankfully not recommending the use of an exception-handling block to catch `std::range_error`, it should be preferable to use ordinary `operator[]`.  If you develop the habit of using `.at` for all your vector accessors in a production environment, all you will achieve is to annoy your tech lead. ;)

Comment: Additional note: a more useful recommendation is to call `myDeck.reserve(52)` before the loop.  This is actually something that surprisingly few developers do, but one that can have a _massive_ performance impact in some cases.  This is a habit I wholeheartedly recommend.

Comment: If your compiler supports it, I would look into the syntactic sugar "for(const auto&card : cards) card.toString();", or even into std::foreach :). PS: The toString method must be const for the syntax to work... remove the const keyword if thats not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `main` need to know there are exactly 52 cards in the deck? It can just as easily work without such knowledge.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Card> theDeck = createDeck();
    for(Card card : theDeck){
        std::cout << card.toString();
    }
}
```

You will probably be wanting to output `Card`s in multiple places in your program, why should all those places have to know there is a `toString` method that provides a representation of a `Card`? You can directly `<<` values into streams by defining a

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Card card)
{
    return os << card.toString(); // or moving the body of toString here
}
```

And then you can `std::copy` the deck into `std::cout`

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Card> theDeck = createDeck();
    std::copy(theDeck.begin(), theDeck.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Card>(std::cout));
}
```